# Strange behavior from lag(), skipping over certain rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table we'll call `service`, toy version is:

```
CREATE TABLE service (
  service_id   SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id    INTEGER      NOT NULL REFERENCES client (client_id),
  service_date TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL CHECK (service_date::DATE <= CURRENT_DATE),

-- system fields
  added_by     INTEGER      NOT NULL REFERENCES staff (staff_id),
  added_at     TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  changed_by   INTEGER      NOT NULL REFERENCES staff (staff_id),
  changed_at   TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  is_deleted   BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
)
```

The last five system fields are for database bookkeeping, and to enable soft (front end) deletion.

There's another table `service_log` which, together with `service` allows us to view a full revision history for each record in `service`.  Fields of `service_log` are the same as `service`, plus a few other fields that facilitate the revision history.  On update or insert to `service`, the state of the data is recorded as an insert to `service_log`. Obviously `service_log.service_id` is not a primary key nor is it unique, since each service record may have multiple revisions.

Our database has security features preventing hard (database-level) deletion of records.  However, while investigating a bug I wanted to rule out the possibility that there may have been records hard-deleted from `service` but with evidence still present in `service_log`.  The following query looking for `service_log` records *without* `service_id` present in `service` returns ~800 records (about 0.5% of all services since 2020):

```
WITH services_in_context AS (
    SELECT service_id,
        lag(service_id) OVER (ORDER BY service_id) AS prev_id
    FROM service
    WHERE service_date::DATE >= '1/1/2020'::DATE
)

SELECT DISTINCT log.service_id
FROM service_log log
INNER JOIN services_in_context s
    ON log.service_id BETWEEN s.prev_id + 1 AND s.service_id - 1
ORDER BY log.service_id DESC;
```

However, the anomaly goes away when I restructure the query to use `GENERATE_SERIES()`. And the "missing" rows from `service` are actually there when I query them individually.

All this leads me to believe that `lag(service_id) OVER (ORDER BY service_id)` is skipping some records in the table.  Which makes me think maybe the index postgres created for the primary key is corrupt?  Is this the likely culprit, and if so what is the best way to fix it?  Is there potentially a different reason `lag()` is missing some primary keys?

Comment: `l.service_id BETWEEN s.prev_id + 1 AND s.service_id - 1` -- Are you sure `service_id` is generated in a strictly **serial** way? Sequences and Identities produce gaps.

Comment: Most likely I'm missing something here but a traditional anti-join will find the missing rows, as in `select l.* from service_log l left join service s on s.service_id = l.service_id where s.service_id is null`.

Comment: I'm certain `service_id` is serial; it's not nullable and its default value is `nextval('service_service_id_seq'::regclass)`.  There is no way to override this default value on the front end.  As for the traditional anti-join, your query returns zero rows.  The thing I want to know is why `lag()` is misbehaving.

Comment: But instead of guessing you may perform a `select` from the CTE passing one of the "missing" id to the `between` predicate and find what are previous and current values. It's hard to imagine your situation without actual data

Comment: `nextval()` produces gaps.

Comment: @TheImpaler Either way, the issue is not any gaps that may or may not be in the sequence, but the fact that `lag()` is producing additional gaps that are not truly there.  As evidenced by your anti-join, or another `GENERATE_SERIES` query, or individually querying rows that are, indeed, present.

Comment: @astentx I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is reason for the `WHERE` statement and what is the `service_date` for the records returned? Your `WHERE` statement can easily create a gap.

```
WITH services_in_context AS (
    SELECT service_id,
        lag(service_id) OVER (ORDER BY service_id) AS prev_id
    FROM service
)

SELECT DISTINCT log.service_id
FROM service_log log
INNER JOIN services_in_context s
    ON log.service_id BETWEEN s.prev_id + 1 AND s.service_id - 1
ORDER BY log.service_id DESC;
```

Your requirement can also be more easily satisfied by a simple `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT sl.*
FROM service_log sl
LEFT JOIN service s ON s.service_id = sl.service_id 
WHERE s.service_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized this was the issue!  The `service_date` for these services are all previous to 2020.